# Is this purported video showing the ending real or fake?

Tags: code-geass

I am confused. Could someone please take a look at [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gNhyzoq4mxo) purportedly showing the English and Japanese versions of the Code Geass Ending and tell if it is real or fake?

Answer (score 4):

This is fake. Unless someone can point me to the dvd/blu-ray version this can be found on. Definitely not original airing.  Further more the art seems a little off to be Lelouch, (chin is a little sharp).  Chances are this is spliced in from another anime.

P.S. - Not biased response, as I personally think he lived due to the Lelouch of the Rebellion movie they are working on as well as the popular code immortality factor.

Comment: It's also worth noting that when I watched the Japanese original dub with subtitles, no such scene appeared.

Answer (score 1):

That video is very fake.
It' was shown to be fan made years ago.
There's many ways you can see it's a fake:
The zoom on his face was of terrible quality.
The broadcast station's logo disappeared during the zoom.
There was no music during the zoom.
People checked the Japanese ending and the zoom wasn't there.
It was highly suspicious that this extra scene was nowhere to be found except on youtube channels of people who (falsely!) claimed Lelouch was alive.
How did they get it?
Why are they the only ones to have this scene?
Why was it dropped?
Etc.

The epilogue **WAS** remade, though, but not like this.
They made a new epilogue for the Zero Requiem blu-ray, it dropped the often misunderstood hay cart scene and replaced it with C.C. narrating to the audience, explicitly telling us that Lelouch is truly dead.
Here are here words: *"A young man dies. He had the power to change the world, to create a new order. The world feared him, hated him. But, I know he died with a smile on his face. Only those who have realised their dream will truly understand that feeling of utter contentment. So, this is not a tragedy. And whenever I feel sad or cry at night, I sing a song. A song of man's making. Zero Requiem!"*

You can watch the new epilogue here: https://streamable.com/d8dji
Notice the differences: not just a zoom, but actual new art of very high quality (and very beautiful), actual music, and C.C.'s voice actress talking to us!